# Can I create a shared folder on remote machine?

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to automate the Account Creation process in Active Directory and I want to create the user home directory on a server and then I want it to become a shared folder with some user permissions.

I can create folder on that machine (remote machine) but I cannot convert it to a shared folder. Is there a way I can do that. Note I can create shared folder locally and can set permissions but cannot do that when the machine is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which language are you using to script ?

You can do exactly what you are doing localy, on a remote computer using [psExec from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb897553). You'll find at th end of this post [how to do it in ldap mixed in with WMI](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85172-remotely-creating-home-drive/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I've used psExec tool but don't know if I can use its API to create the shared folder on remote machine. Is it possible?

Comment: ok great I just saw the other link and it is using the psexec tool. Is there any other way to do this? I just don't want to rely on third party. Also I am using C#

Comment: You can use with PSSesion (WSMan) in PowerShell 2.0